# Does DynamoDB Track Item Modification Times?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there some sort of hidden field or other way to tell in DynamoDB when an item was put or modified? Of course I could add these fields, but I was wondering if that is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS recently announced [DynamoDB Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/dynamodb-streams-preview/) that is the answer to your question.